# class constraint in data kind definition

Tags: haskell, type-families

I couldn't make the following compile:

```
class Typeable f => Foo f where
    data Bar :: Typeable
```

In other words, I wanted to define a class `Foo`, which have an associated type that must be an instance of `Typeable`.

It looks like I can define the same thing with `FunctionalDependencies`:

```
class (Typeable b,Typeable f) => Foo f b | f -> b where
```

So how can I do the same thing with `TypeFamilies`?

Comment: Do you mean an associate type, or associated data? The difference is pretty fundamental, and this question makes a lot more sense if you mean an associated type. That is, `type Bar ...` in the class definition. The comparison to fundeps just doesn't work with associated data.

Comment: The actual requirement is more like associated data, since `Bar` is going to be defined at the same time as a `Foo` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked it, but I believe this should work:

```
class (Typeable f, Typeable (Bar f)) => Foo f where data Bar f :: *
```